# Strange Kotlin error after update: Duplicate entry

Tags: java, kotlin, android-studio-3.1

Please check code below:

```
class HTMLEngine : View {
    class HREFOffset(var YOffset: Int, var href: String)
    class ChapterHolder(var chapter: Int, var chapter_body: Node)
```

Kotlin compiler says :

> Cause: duplicate entry:
>   com/app/view/HTMLEngine$ChapterHolder.class

Update:

I reverted to 4.3.1, everything worked fine for a day, then again problem appeared. I doubt it's because of latest Kotlin plugin.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project and rebuild